# Basic bottom up algorithm homework

Tags: java

So here is the problem my professor gave me:

Develop a bottom-up algorithm to teach someone how to send a flattering e-mail to your professor.

This is the example based on cooking that he gave us to base it off of:

1. Chef.Mix(eggs, flour, sugar, milk, mixing bowl)
2. Chef.Preheat(oven)
3. Chef.insert(batter, oven)
4. Oven.bake(batter)
5. Chef.remove(batter, oven)

This is what I got, any problems or did I mess up by adding the "path" I guess you can call it at the end of each step.

1. Sender.Press(PcPowerButton)
2. Sender.Open(Browser,PC)
3. Sender.LogOn(EmailClient,Browser,PC)
4. Sender.Click(ComposeButton,EmailClient,Browser,Pc)
5. Sender.Click(AddressBox,EmailClient,Browser,PC)
6. Sender.Type(RecieverAddress,AddressBox,EmailClient,Browser,Pc)
7. Sender.Click(SubjectBox,EmailClient,Browser,PC)
8. Sender.Type(FlatteringText,SubjectBox,EmailClient,Browser,PC)
9. Sender.Click(SendButton,EmailClient,Browser,PC)

thank you so much for the help :)

This is what I've changed it to thus far

1. Sender.Press(PcPowerButton)
2. Sender.Open(Browser,PC)
3. Sender.LogOn(EmailClient,Internet)
4. Sender.Click(ComposeButton,EmailClient,Internet)
5. Sender.Click(AddressBox,NewMessage)
6. Sender.Type(RecieverAddress,AddressBox,NewMessage)
7. Sender.Click(SubjectBox,NewMessage)
8. Sender.Type(FlatteringText,SubjectBox,NewMessage)
9. Sender.Click(SendButton,NewMessage)

Comment: Suggestion: have more than one class involved. Perhaps involve `EmailService` and `Recipient`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, wouldn't EmailClient and RecieverAddress be the same thing?

Comment: notice that his first method he combined eggs, flour, sugar, milk, and a mixing bowl into batter. From that point on he wasn't sending all of the ingredients, just the batter to the oven.  Perhaps you could do something similar instead of sending the EmailClient, Browser, AND PC to every method.

Comment: Great idea, I changed (Browser,PC) into Internet. Any idea how to combine EmailClient,Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few of points.

1. Note that the example does not include steps like "Oven.TurnOn()" and "Oven.SetTemprature()". Instead it just says "Oven.Preheat()" and later "Oven.Bake(batter)". So, this is a matter of abstraction. The programming primitive can be low level, or a high level one. A high level primitive encapsulates larger behavior / functionality. You could presumably invent and use higher level primitives.
2. You seem to be using the object oriented paradigm. The primitives / methods should belong to the appropriate object.

So, conceivably, you could have the following primitives.

1. PC.PowerOn()
2. OS.Login(SenderUserID, SenderPassword)
3. OS.Start(Browser)
4. Browser.Navigate(EmailWebsiteURL)
5. EmailWebsite.Login(SenderUserID, SenderPassword)
6. EmailWebsite.Compose(ProfessorEmail, FlatteringSubject, FlatteringBody)
7. EmailWebsite.Send()

You could also try to program the process of discovering something flattering about the professor, if you want to make it interesting.

1. FlatteringAttributes = Professor.SelectAttributes(Flattering)
2. EmailBody = Sender.Write(Theme, FlatteringAttributes)